# Quickblox bloating webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, quickblox

I am using Quickblox https://www.npmjs.com/package/quickblox in my CRA react application and I am having a problem of quickblox bloating my bundle size by 1Mb.

I saw this using bundle analyzer.

Currently, I am importing it inside my project

```
import * as QB from 'quickblox/quickblox';
```

I tried importing it by modularizing it with

```
import {init, chat} from 'quickblox/quickblox';
```

but it is not working. Does anybody know is it possible to import just those functionalities from Quickblox. Can it be treeshaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lib has weight of [433kb](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=quickblox@2.12.4) and not supports tree shaking (it not exports as `esm` as basic requirement).

So it doesn't matter how you import it, it will bring the entire lib.